# R linear regression: "only using the first two of 5 regression coefficients"

Tags: r, excel, linear-regression

I am trying to plot the linear regression from a set of data I got from laboratory.
The data I am using is this table:
[image: table photo from excel]

the code I am running is this:

```
tabella_1_final$mg.ml <- gsub(",",".",tabella_1_1$mg.ml)

tabella_1_final$Abs.540.nm <- gsub(",",".",tabella_1_1$Abs.540.nm)

plot(tabella_1_final, type = "l", main = "tabella 1", xlab = "mg/ml", ylab = "Abs 540 nm", panel.first=grid())

par(new=TRUE)

abline(lm(tabella_1_final))
```

Running the code give me this:

[image: plots R]

But as I remade the graph in Excel the result is strikingly different:
[image: plots Excel]

RStudio gives me this error that I cannot resolve

Warning message:
In abline(lm(tabella_1_final)) :
only using the first two of 6 regression coefficients

Do anyone knows how to avoid this and get the correct linear regression?   Thanks.

```
summary(lm(tabella_1_final))) output:
Call:
lm(formula = tabella_1_final)

Residuals:
ALL 6 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)     -2.833e-18        NaN     NaN      NaN
Abs.540.nm0.034  1.250e-01        NaN     NaN      NaN
Abs.540.nm0.06   2.500e-01        NaN     NaN      NaN
Abs.540.nm0.128  5.000e-01        NaN     NaN      NaN
Abs.540.nm0.191  7.500e-01        NaN     NaN      NaN
Abs.540.nm0.268  1.000e+00        NaN     NaN      NaN

Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:    NaN 
F-statistic:   NaN on 5 and 0 DF,  p-value: NA
```

```
structure(list(mg.ml = c("0", "0.125", "0.25", "0.5", "0.75", 
"1"), Abs.540.nm = c("0", "0.034", "0.06", "0.128", "0.191", 
"0.268")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Edit:
Trying the rio package managed to get the line even more off from the data:
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmhj8.png)

Comment: Or better show us the data you work with. Instead of image add the result of `dput(head(tabella_1_1))`. It looks like you have more than two columns in the data.frame.

Comment: you havent converted the strings to numeric

Comment: How do I canvert them in numeric? I pasted the table from excel with copy.table

Comment: Try this `abline(lm(mg.ml ~ Abs.540.nm, data = tabella_1_final))`

Comment: Istrel I recieve the same error message in the console.

Comment: `tabella_1_final <- type.convert(tabella_1_1, dec = ',', as.is = TRUE)`

Comment: You're copying from Excel and apparently using a comma as decimal sign. Do yourself a favour, install and load package "rio" and pull your `data.frame` out of the clipboard as hazzle-free as: `import('clipboard', dec=',')`

Comment: since you have already changed the `,` into `.` you should just use `df <- typeconvert(df, as.is = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested by user rawr, the problem was that I tried to apply a linear regression to characters and not numbers. Basically I was making lm() do a polinomial regression on factors!

There is probably a line of code to convert the characters into numbers without doing manually, but I didi it by recreating the dataframe from scratch.

If you like me have copied the dataframe from the clipboard, use dput(head(yourdfhere)) to print out the vectors of which the dataframe is made of and then change them by hand.

```
mg.ml = c(0, 0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1)
Abs.540.nm = c(0, 0.034, 0.06, 0.128, 0.191, 0.268)
tabella <- data.frame(mg.ml, Abs.540.nm)
plot(tabella, type = "p", main = "tabella 1", xlab = "mg/ml", ylab = "Abs 540 nm")
grid()
abline(lm(Abs.540.nm ~ mg.ml, data = tabella), col="red")
```

A big thank you to my professor that helped me understand my error!